# Select something (events, birthday, post etc) in date range

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I try figure out something with fql and I made some select query which showing friends who have a birthday in selected day.

I can't figure it out how to make some time range in the query.

```
$fql_n = "SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
AND strlen(birthday_date) != 0 ORDER BY birthday_date";
```

The Facebook date is in format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `birthday_date` and `birthday` are strings.  There's really not a way to search on a range.

You could specify a list of dates and use `IN`

```
WHERE birthday_date IN ('05/30/1990','05/29/1990')
```

Comment: That's not working. returns nothing when i add this statement. i changed the date to bigger range of course so it's not that no one of my friends hasn't birthday between them ;) I'll be greatful for another solution. cheers

Comment: It's not a range. As I said, you can't use a range. You would have to have specific dates in the list.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the day you want to have birthday

```
SELECT name, birthday_date 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 
    FROM friend 
    WHERE uid1=me()
)
AND (strpos(lower(birthday_date),"08/01") >=0 OR strpos(lower(birthday_date),"08/02") >=0)
```

// this will fetch birthday for august 1 and 2, use birthday_date so you have MM/DD/YYYY format.